# Help Needed with Keyboard Layout Toggling on Raspberry Pi 4B (Arabic/English)

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Hello Raspberry Pi Community,

I'm experiencing challenges in configuring my Raspberry Pi 4B to toggle between Arabic and English keyboard layouts. Despite numerous attempts with different methods, I haven't been able to set up a convenient way to switch between the two layouts. I'm using a dual-language keyboard (with both English and Arabic characters printed on the keys) on Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy).

System Details:

Raspberry Pi Model: Raspberry Pi 4B
OS Version: Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy) with desktop (Release date: May 3rd, 2023, System: 32-bit, Kernel version: 6.1, Debian version: 11 (bullseye), Size: 872MB)
Keyboard: Dual-language (English and Arabic)
Methods Tried:

Editing /etc/default/keyboard:

Updated with XKBLAYOUT="us,ar" and tried different XKBOPTIONS such as grp:alt_shift_toggle, grp:ctrl_shift_toggle, grp:caps_toggle.
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration:

Executed and followed the configuration steps, but it didn't enable the toggling between layouts.
Manual setxkbmap Settings:

Tried setxkbmap -layout us,ar -option grp:alt_shift_toggle, which also didn't enable layout toggling.
Autostart Configuration:

Included the setxkbmap command in ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart without success.
Graphical Tools and Keyboard Layout Handler:

Utilized graphical options in the desktop environment and the keyboard layout handler, but to no avail.
Despite these efforts, my system remains stuck on the US layout, and I cannot switch to the Arabic layout. I'm looking for any advice, suggestions, or insights that could help me resolve this issue.

I appreciate any help you can provide!